# displaying popup message after form submission in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

How to display a conformation message in a popup box after submitting values into database in cakephp

***View***

```
<table style="border:none;width:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('sender_name', array(
        'label' => false, 'maxlength' => 100, 'style' => 'border:1px dashed gray;border-radius:5px;height:20px'
    )); ?></td>
     <td>E-Mail</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('sender_email', array(
        'label' => false, 'maxlength' => 100, 'style' => 'border:1px dashed gray;border-radius:5px;height:20px'
    )); ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Your comment</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('sender_comment', array(
        'label' => false, 'cols' => 50, 'rows' => 1, 'style' => 'border:1px dashed gray;border-radius:5px;'
    )); ?></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Submit'); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here i am posting my comment.. After posting the comment i need to display the popup message

**CONTROLLER**

```
function newsdetail($id)
{
    $com = $this->comment->find('all', array('conditions' => array('comment.comment_id' => $id), 'order' => array('comment.post_time DESC')));
    $this->set('values', $com);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->comment->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your message has been submitted');
        }
    }
}
```

Here the message is displaying in the top of the page.. but i need the message to me displayed in a popup box.
can anyone help me in this please..

Answer (score 1):

First create flash message element in your /Views/Elements folder , example: popup.ctp

```
<script>
   alert("<?php echo $message; ?>");
</script>
```

in your newsdetal function set flash message like:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('Your message has been submitted','popup');
```

but I recommend you to use some of jquery modal plugin for positive user experience